# $N$-body simulation with varying neutrino mass

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, neutrinos, data

I am trying to find a picture of the $N$-body simulations that shows the LSS. Particularly I am looking for different neutrino masses without the CDM. For instance pictures likes this

[image]

But with more varying/different neutrino masses. I am looking for articles